# docker - Copy bin directory , folder not found

Tags: docker, .net-6.0

I have a dockerfile for my .net 6 project that just has the following:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
EXPOSE 8081
COPY bin/Release/net6/ App/
WORKDIR /App
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "IdentityManager.dll"]
```

but when i try to build this, i get an error that the 'bin/Release/net6' folder isn't found.  See the attached image to see my build command, and the file explorer showing that the folder does indeed exist.  Is there something going on here that i'm not seeing?  Thanks!

[image]

Comment: maybe try the absolute path.

Comment: try `/bin/Release/net6` (note the leading slash)

Comment: I can't use the absolute path because this has to work on many other machines that might not be configured like mine.

Comment: /bin/Release/net6 does not work, neither does ./bin/Release/net6

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "this has to work on many other machines". Normally, you are building the image on one machine and use it on lots of other machines (and this will work 100% if the image was built successfully). Why would you want to build the same image on multiple other machines?

Comment: I'm testing it on my development box, and it also needs to run on my CI/CD server.  It's a moot issue, i get the same error.

Comment: do you have a `.dockerignore` file that ignores the files you want to copy by any chance?

Comment: That was it.  I had 2 dockerignore files, and the second one i didn't know about was causing issues.  Thank you!

Comment: It is possible that you have your Dockerfile in a project folder, and the solution file in its parent folder. Take a look at this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/containers/container-build?view=vs-2022#docker-build